# Can a customer "rip off" a restaurant?

Tags: expressions

I often hear the expression, "Rip-off restaurant or company".
But I wonder if we can say "customers rip off a restarant 
by trying to eat more than they paid for."

I think people woulbe able to understand what I mean if I said, 
"let's rip them(the restaurant) off" at the restarant by its context
but not sure it is a common way to use the expression.

Thank you!

Comment: The sentence works fine, although it isn’t a nice thing to do! The term that I’ve heard more often when it comes to cheating restaurants is “dine and dash,” meaning exactly what it says: you eat and then run off without paying.

Comment: Oh I forgot to say an "all-you-can-eat restaurant". Will that be still ok?

Comment: In any case when you are not paying for something that you should be paying for, you are ripping someone off. “Dine and dash” usually refers to a meal that you sit down for and are waited on, and not a buffet.

Comment: I am talking about the case where I paid for the buffet but try to eat more than the money I spend. Like eating $50 worth food at $20 buffet.

Comment: In most cases, buffets are “all you can eat” and only have a flat entry fee, or are included as a complimentary addition to some other service (like a hotel breakfast buffet). As long as you are paying that fee or for the other service, you aren’t ripping anyone off if you eat more than the value you payed for.

Comment: That’s true, eating a lot at an all-you-can-eat restaurant is not “ripping off” the business.

Comment: Thank you! I got the meaning now!